# python lxml получение текста с html-атрибутами

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, lxml

Производил поиск определенного элемента:

```
game_descriptions = html.cssselect('#game_area_description')[0]
```

В результате получил такой блок:

```
<div id="game_area_description" class="game_area_description">
    <strong>Самая популярная игра в Steam</strong>
    <br>Ежедневно миллионы игроков по всему миру вступают в битву от лица одного.....
```

Как получить весь текст  с html атрибутами?

`.text` выдает пустые строки

Update:

```
import lxml.html

def get_html(request):
    return lxml.html.fromstring(request.text)

html = get_html(r)
game_descriptions = html.cssselect('#game_area_description')[0]
```

Comment: А то, что вы получили чем не подходит? там и атрибуты, и html

Comment: необходимо избавиться от div id = "game_area_description", чтобы сохранить остальную часть в базе данных

Comment: Интересно.. а попробуйте: `''.join([html.tostring(child) for child in game_descriptions.iterchildren()])`

Comment: 'HtmlElement' object has no attribute 'tostring'

Comment: у вас `html` это кто? `from lxml import html` ? Добавьте в вопрос минимальный воспроизводимый пример, чтобы не играли в загадки

Comment: Обновил код ниже

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
import lxml.html


def to_string(node):
    return lxml.html.tostring(node, encoding='unicode')


text = """<div id="game_area_description" class="game_area_description">
<strong>Самая популярная игра в Steam</strong>
<br>Ежедневно миллионы игроков по всему миру вступают в битву от лица одного....."""

root = lxml.html.fromstring(text)
game_descriptions = root.cssselect('#game_area_description')[0]

print(''.join(to_string(child) for child in game_descriptions.iterchildren()))
```

Консоль:

```
<strong>Самая популярная игра в Steam</strong>
<br>Ежедневно миллионы игроков по всему миру вступают в битву от лица одного.....
```

Comment: поменял название переменной, чтобы не было путаницы. в качестве node попадают элементы из iterchildren

Comment: Спасибо, заработало. Просто первоначально хотел использовать текст в мобильном приложении, но думал, как сохранить похожую разметку, поэтому и решил сохранять с html - тегами

Comment: @danilshik Если помогло, вы знаете что делать :)